# Incomprehensible result of a multithread code

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I will start a C Programming project that will be used multithread. Before I start the project, I have written a code for practice. My purpose is to see how mutex and threads works. However it is not work properly. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

pthread_mutex_t myMutex;
char myStrings[100][30];
int i=0;

void *PrintThread1()
{
    printf("this is initial of FIRST Thread\n");
    for (int j=0; j<33; j++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        strcpy(myStrings[i], "This is FIRST thread");
        i++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *PrintThread2()
{
    printf("this is initial of SECOND Thread\n");
    for (int j=0; j<33; j++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        strcpy(myStrings[i], "This is SECOND thread");
        i++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *PrintThread3()
{
    printf("this is initial of THIRD Thread\n");
    for (int j=0; j<33; j++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&myMutex);
        strcpy(myStrings[i], "This is THIRD thread");
        i++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&myMutex);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t firstThread, secondThread, thirdThread;
    //pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL);
    //pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    //pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    int ft;
    ft = pthread_create(&firstThread, NULL, PrintThread1(), NULL);
    if (ft){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", ft);
        exit(-1);
    }
    ft = pthread_create(&secondThread, NULL, PrintThread2(), NULL);
    if (ft){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", ft);
        exit(-1);
    }
    ft = pthread_create(&thirdThread, NULL, PrintThread3(), NULL);
    if (ft){
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", ft);
        exit(-1);
    }

    pthread_join(firstThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(secondThread, NULL);
    pthread_join(thirdThread, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&myMutex);

    for (int j=0;j<100; j++) {
        printf("String[%d] = %s\n",j,myStrings[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return -1;
}
```

When I execute this code, my result is:

```
this is initial of FIRST Thread
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I can't figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ft = pthread_create(&firstThread, NULL, PrintThread1(), NULL);
```

should read

```
ft = pthread_create(&firstThread, NULL, PrintThread1, NULL);
```

and similarly for all your `pthread_create` calls.

To use `pthread_create`, you need to pass it the address of a thread-start routine, which you do in C by writing the name of a function *without* the function-call parentheses.

As you have written it, you *call* the intended thread-start routine, *on the main thread*, and pass whatever it *returns* to `pthread_create` to be the thread-start routine.  But it never returns, because it calls `pthread_exit`, which (since `pthread_create` hasn't been called yet, so there is only one thread) terminates the entire program.

Unfortunately, you have to crank the warnings *way* up before the compiler will catch this mistake, and even then it's not super clear what the problem is:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -pthread test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:60:45: warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 3 
  of ‘pthread_create’ between function pointer and ‘void *’ [-Wpedantic]
     ft = pthread_create(&firstThread, NULL, PrintThread1(), NULL);
                                             ^
```

Without `-pedantic`, no complaint.